# How to reduce loading time of mobile app or how to reduce cache memory of app?

Tags: android

I am developing a Mobile app with lots of images and data. The size of the app is around 10 MB. But after installation the total size is as follows:

- Total- 31.40MB;
- App- 9.79MB and
- Cache- 86.56MB.

When ever someone installs for the 1st time, it takes almost 1min 30sec to open, but after the cache is built it opens smoothly. Is there any way to reduce this time taken to load? The problem again surfaces once cache memory is cleaned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not clearing the bitmaps properly or their are memory leaks. Their can be many reasons we can assume. Without looking at your code it is difficult to suggest for proper answer. Pls share your code for more analysis. Also generate Hprof and view it using MAT(Memory Analyzer Tool) tool for memory leaks.